# Unable to invoke PropertyChanged event on a C# ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, event-handling, concurrentdictionary

I am trying to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` in `C#` and handle events whenever new items added to the dictionary but I am not able to do so and the code is below

```
public class TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary
    {
        #region Singleton
        private static volatile ConcurrentDictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, IDataPipesService> _instance;
        private static readonly object Sync = new object();
        private static readonly object Lock = new object();

        public static event EventHandler  PropertyChanged;

        public static ConcurrentDictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, IDataService> Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance != null) return _instance;
                lock (Sync)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new ConcurrentDictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, IDataService>();
                    }
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
        #endregion Singleton

        public  void TryAdd(KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair, IDataPipesService service) {
            Instance.TryAdd(keyValuePair, service);
            PropertyChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Here is how I am adding to the dictionary

```
  var dataService = _kernel.Get<IDataService>();
TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary.Instance.TryAdd(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(param.TagPrefix, param.TopicName), dataService);
```

When add an item to the dictionary, I expecting to invoke the `ProperyChanged` event as below

```
TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary.PropertyChanged += delegate (object o, EventArgs e)
            {
                foreach (var item in TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary.Instance) {
                    if (!item.Value.Running)
                        //do something
                }
            };
```

When I do the above, `PropertyChanged` event is never invoked, may I know where I went wrong?

Comment: item.Value.IsRunning is not a property of the collection. You need to handle PropertyChanged on the items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are suffering from an encapsulation problem. Seems like you have implemented the Singleton Pattern wrong. You are exposing the underlying collection to the client code. That bypasses the `TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary` logic. That's why your event never gets raised. You are actually invoking `ConcurrentDictionary.TryAdd` instead of `TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary.TryAdd`.

You are adding the new items to the underlying collection directly. 
To fix your code either remove the `Instance` property or implement the Singleton properly. But both versions should implement at least the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

I replaced `PropertyChanged` with `CollectionChanged` (which enables `ObservableCollection` behavior in binding scenarios) and added an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` to enable the collection to be used in `foreach` iterations. Then I implemented the Singleton Pattern properly. By using `Lazy<T>` you can reduce the code to create a single shared thread-safe instance significantly:

```
public sealed class TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary : IEnumerable, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, IDataPipesService>>
{
  public static TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary Instance => 
    TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary._instance.Value;

  public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;    

  private ConcurrentDictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, IDataPipesService> underlyingCollection;
  private static readonly object Sync = new object();    
  private static readonly Lazy<TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary> _instance = 
    new Lazy<TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary>(() => new TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary());

  private TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary()
  {
    this.underlyingCollection = new ConcurrentDictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, IDataPipesService>();
  }

  public void TryAdd(KeyValuePair<string, string> key, IDataPipesService value)
  {
    this.underlyingCollection.TryAdd(key, value);
    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, new KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, IDataPipesService>(key, value)));
  }

  public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, IDataPipesService>> GetEnumerator()
  {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, IDataPipesService> entry in this.underlyingCollection)
    {
      yield return entry;
    }
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return GetEnumerator();
  }

  private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
  }
}
```

Basically `_instance` must reference an instance of `TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary` and not of the underlying collection (like in the original implementation).

Example:

```
TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary.Instance.CollectionChanged += delegate (object o, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, IDataPipesService> item in TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary.Instance)
  {
    ;
  }
};

var dataService = _kernel.Get<IDataService>();
TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary.Instance.TryAdd(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(param.TagPrefix, param.TopicName), dataService);
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I iterate through each value in the `TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary.Instance`, `item.Value` doesnt work any more and also Instance.Any doesnt. Is there way I can use these as I would on a collection?

Comment: What do you mean? It's in the example. You can use `foreach`.

Comment: `item` just has `Equals, GetHashCode, GetType and ToString` in it.

Comment: This is because the collection only implemented `IEnumerable`. So the items returned by the `foreach` are of type object and require a cast before you can use them. I updated the answer. `TopicTaskConcurrentDictionary` now implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Now you can use it like you expect it, without casting.